# HTML5 pattern allow specific special characters

Tags: html, input, special-characters

I have an input text field in my form but i don't know how to filter the input that can all letters and special characters but will not accept numbers.

```
   <input  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,25}" maxlength="25" type="text" required="required" style="height:20px"  value="">
```

It doesn't accept when i enter my middle name "pacaña"

how could i alter the pattern that can accept all characters/special-characters and other special characters like ñ?

Comment: So if you want to accept all special characters, than why you are using a regex with A-Za-z?

Comment: I'm sorry.. i just updated my question.

Comment: If you just want no digits, but everything else should be allowed – then use a negated character class.

Comment: how could i possibly do that sir?

Comment: What do you mean by “special characters”? There are over 100,000 different characters. Which of them do you wish to allow?

Comment: i wish to allow all alphabets including the special character "ñ" sir.. pls help..

Comment: here's what i did
 Can accept ñ already but it do not allow alphabets anymore. how can i allow alphabets with this? `?[^\d\uhhhh]`

Answer (score 10):

```
pattern="[^0-9]*"
```

- `[…]` matches a single character
- `^` anything except the following (when within `[]`)
- `0-9` digits zero through nine
- `*` between zero and unlimited times

Answer (score 3):

For Not allowing Specific Symbols (dont allow , or .)

```
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="[^-,]+" title="'-' is not allowed">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow any special symbols : [A-Za-z\W+]

```html
 <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="country_code">Special Symbols Not Allowed:</label>
      <input type="text"  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,25}" title="Special characters are not allowed!"><br><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

<br><br>

<form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="country_code">Special Symbols Allowed:</label>
      <input type="text"  pattern="[A-Za-z\W+]{1,25}" title="Special characters are not allowed!"><br><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I crashed into the same problem, wanted to allow french accents into a text field...
After a bit of trial and error, turns out you can use `pattern="^[\p{L}]${1,25}` to allow ASCII letters and Unicode variants, accented letters and special characters.

Comment: Sorry, but your regex is flawed: https://regex101.com/r/MO9WcA/1