# How do I find special characters in an input string?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const password = document.getElementById('password')

password.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  let input = e.target.value

  const specialCharacter = "!@#$%^&*()"

  if(input.indexOf(specialCharacter) > -1) {
    console.log('detected special character')
  } else {
    console.log('not special')
  }
})
```

```html
  <input type="password" id='password' placeholder="Enter Password">
```

I want the code to know when a special character is typed in, but I can't seem to get why special characters are not detected.

Comment: You have to check for each character individually.

Comment: because you're not checking for special characters, you're checking for whether the password contains the _entire string_ `!@#$%^&*()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must iterate over all the characters in the `specialCharacter` string, and do `indexOf` on each character. This code currently checks if the exact string `"!@#$%^&*()"` is located in the input. For example:

```
const password = document.getElementById('password')

password.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    let input = e.target.value
    ...
    const specialCharacter = "!@#$%^&*()"
    for (var i in specialCharacter) { // Iterate over the string
        if(input.indexOf(specialCharacter[i]) > -1) {
            console.log('detected special character')
        } else {
            console.log('not special')
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to search for the entire sequence of special characters in `input`, but what you should be doing is check if ANY of the special characters is present within `input`

You should probably do this using Regex

```
const password = document.getElementById('password')

password.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  let input = e.target.value

  const specialCharacterRegex = /[!@#$%^&*()]+/

  if(specialCharacterRegex.test(input)) {
    console.log('detected special character')
  } else {
    console.log('not special')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the `pattern` attribute on the input field to determine what characters are allowed.

This question will be a good starting point, I believe
[HTML5 pattern allow specific special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282049/html5-pattern-allow-specific-special-characters)

Then, you will have to make sure you also have data sanitation in your backend, but I will leave that to you, and for another question :)